# Trying to update object with Mongoose gives TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Why does this code produce an `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'`? The `project` object exists and is singular.

```
/** Update project */
exports.update = function (req, res, next) {
    var projectId = req.params.id;

    Project.findById(projectId, function (err, project) {

        if (project) {
            project.screens[0] = project.screens[0] || {};
            project.screens[0].name = 'Test screen';
            project.screens[0].data = req.body.data;
            project.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json(500, err);
                }
                else {
                    res.json(200, 'Update complete');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.json(404, 'PROJECT_NOT_FOUND');
        }
    });
};
```

Schema:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    dateCreated: Date,
    dateUpdated: Date,
    createdByUserId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    screens: [ { name: String, data: Schema.Types.Mixed } ]
    //awesomeness: Number
    //Schema.Types.Mixed
    // ProjectSchema.methods.greet = function() { return 'Hello, ' + this.name; }; 
});

mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Console output just before `project.save`:

```
Logged 'project': { name: 'My First Project',
  slug: 'my-first-project',
  dateCreated: Wed Jan 29 2014 22:26:22 GMT+0100 (CET),
  _id: 52e971fe003687a492000002,
  __v: 0,
  screens: [ { data: 'testWeld', name: 'Test screen' } ] }
```

Comment: I've done a workaround using `Project.update` instead.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

I just completed debugging a problem with the same symptoms.

In your schema you have the following mongoose subdocument:

```
screens: [ { name: String, data: Schema.Types.Mixed } ]
```

I would agree with you that it would be intuitive if the following steps worked:

```
project.screens[0] = project.screens[0] || {};
project.screens[0].name = 'Test screen';
project.screens[0].data = req.body.data;

project.save(function(err)
```

However, after re-reading the mongoose documents ([Mongoose subdocs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)) the appropriate apis to add subdocuments need to be used as there is some casting/extra work that goes on.

For example, this got rid of the error message:

```
project.screens.push({ name: 'Test screen', data: req.body.data });
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't seeing the forest for the trees before. Glad you posted log output because now it's obvious something is logging. Save either takes no arguments or a three element callback which you can see in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter#model_Model-save).

So your code should be more like:

```
// project.save(err) { <-- is an object and not a callback
project.save(function(err, project, numAffected) {
    if (err) {
        res.json(500, err);
    }
    else {
        res.json(200, 'Update complete');
    }
});
```

The whole Object#< Object > thing is because there is no reference at all. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Sorry, still gives the same error. And me omitting the `project`, `numAffected` parameters shouldn't void the method call, based on what I know about JS methods. And `Project.findById` sure returns _something_...

Comment: Seems like `project` just contains the JSON structure and is not a proper Mongoose Model. Hmm...

Comment: I've done a workaround using `Project.update` instead.

Comment: Actually if you look at the code you posted you **omitted the callback function**, which is the only parameter to .save. Guessing you got the update call right then. BTW .save only differs from .update as what MongoDB calls an "upsert" which will insert or update an additional fields. But this is unlikely to matter to you under Mongoose.

Comment: The code reads `project.save(function(err) { ... });` - that `function` is the callback, right?